# Regex using Hexcode for Euro symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex expression for Euro currency symbol.

I wrote `/[x80]/g` but its not working. Any ideas how to get it matching?

Comment: You could just use it in the regex pattern - `/€/g`, no need for a hex code. If you need it, you should use `/\u20AC/g`

Comment: try out here http://regexr.com/

Comment: What makes you think that `[x80]` matches the euro symbol?

Comment: @JJJ probably 'cause [unicode x80 is €](http://www.codetable.net/hex/80), you should use /u to treat pattern strings as UTF-8

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem is that I cannot use euro symbol as it is coming as a hex or unicode. But your solution for unicode /\u20AC/g works! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/[x80]/g` is not working because the `[...]` is a *character class* matching 1 char from the defined set: either `x`, `8` or `0`.

You need to either use the literal `€` (`/€/g`), or, in case there are issues with using the literal euro symbol, you should use `/\u20AC/g`.

```js
var s = "1.500€ - 2.000€";
console.log(s.replace(/\u20AC/g, "EUR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function (){
var str =" test &#x80 one";
   $('#demo0').html(str);//before replace
  str = str.replace(/(&#x80)/g, "euro");
 
$('#demo').html(str);//after replace
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo0"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @tintin   why give a downvote?.it will match the `euro` symbol

Comment: Who ever downvoted, Please give a reason .. This solution works fine. Let me upvote you.

Comment: There's no indication in the question that the OP wants to replace the HTML character entity sequence (which is `&#x80;` by the way). This won't work if the string actually contains the euro character.